# Write recovery scenario - Script is stuck while execution

Tags: qtp, recovery

How can I write a recovery scenario for an event when a QTP script is stuck while executing? How can this event be captured? I mean we are running a overnight batch and the script all of a sudden gets stuck while executing. How can a recovery scenario be written for this event?

Comment: I have been running my scripts continuously for more than 24 hours without using Recovery scenario. It is automated to run every other day & has been running fine for the past 2 years without any issues. My advice is not to use recovery scenario.  It will affect your test performance. You need to provide more details about your test, how you invoke, where it is getting stuck etc.

Comment: It could also be that the QTP is stuck because your PC is unstable, due to faulty RAM, or something. This would make that symtpom very sporadic, but persisting in long test runs. Hence, besides the recommendation in the answer, make sure the hardware involved is 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "catch" QTP freezes by a recovery scenario handler. This happens because QTP uses a lot of memory and the memory usage keeps on increasing for huge test sets. I have found setting up QTP to restart after few runs prevents QTP from hanging. You can try this out and hopefully it would resolve the issue.

Here are the steps:

- Look for Remote Agent in the taskbar or search & start it from Start Menu (`Start Menu\Programs\HP Software\HP Unified Functional Testing\Tools`).
- Right Click the Remote Agent icon & Click on Settings.
- Look for "'Restart testing tool after x runs" setting under Cleanup (see screenshot below).
- Increase the value to a number depending on your test set. I have used 10 for some longer test sets.
- If you still face the issue, try changing the value to a smaller number.

[image]